# HTTPD non available from remote computer

Tags: apache, centos, nagios

I've just installed a Nagios on Centos 7.
I followed the same procedure used for my test environment.
Only difference between test and prod is that the server was not prepared by me, but was an automatic provisioning.
Anyway, i'm failing to undestand why the Nagios web page (and the Apache standard page) is not reachable.
I've already checked with network team for ports blocked and they told me that the traffic is not blocked.

What is wrong with this server?
Here is the config.

```
# netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1503/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12139/httpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/oneagentwatchdo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50001         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/oneagentwatchdo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50002         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/oneagentwatchdo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50003         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/oneagentwatchdo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1758/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1568/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1758/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1568/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           837/dhclient
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           565/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                565/chronyd
```

**FirewallD** is "Inactive".
Even if was active the list of port and service would be:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 80/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

**Iptables** is not installed and therefore not active

```
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

I'm still thinking that there is a block somewhere but i cannot identify where it could be.

Comment: check selinux audit log whether port is blocked `tail /var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: There is nothing descriptive in "automatic provisioning" - see [ask]. Also, installing/providing Nagios is not programming related, thus off topic (see [help/on-topic]) on stackoverflow.

Comment: @OlafKock "Automatic Provisioning" means that the VM was created in GCP providing a ready made server with the basic OS and network configuration. I mentioned Nagios to give information about the context. My problem is related to Apache Web Server that i think OnTopic.

Comment: @AkshayHegde Sekinux is not reporting any blockage.
But if i check the status, i get:
   SELinux status:                 disabled